# Retrieve all Strings and Values from a JSONObject

Tags: java, android

I currently have a JSONObject which contains different types of strings with boolean values. How can I get all the strings and there values in the Object?

JSONObject:

```
{ "1ed1":false, "1ed3":true, "1ep2":true }
```

Comment: Ok, what is the question?

Comment: @Simze How can I get all the strings and there values in the Object. Sorry if it wasn't so clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having only boolean value in your `JsonObject` try following solution :

```
Iterator<?> keys = json.keys(); // json is your `JsonObject`
while( keys.hasNext() ) {
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    Log.e("key",""+key); // This will give you all the keys of your jsonObject, in your case it will be 1ed1,1ed3 etc...
    Log.e("value",""+json.getBoolean(key)); // This will give all the values associated with the key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(your object);
String led1 = jObj.getBoolean("led1");
String led2 = jObj.getBoolean("led2"); 
String led3 = jObj.getString("led3"); // if it is String otherwise the same as above
```

Comment: This is fairly helpful! But how can I do this for all the Strings in the Object rather than just one?